# Updating Company contacts

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV with the company contacts in.

I want to create a script to read the line of the CSV and chack against the current stored in AD.

When I read the contact from AD and then read the line from the CSV, in the screen they look the same but they are failing the does not equal to function.

My question is:

Is it best the read each part of the contact i.e.:

- `contact.firstname` and compare to `compare.firstname`
- `contact.lastname` and compare to `compare.lastname`
- `contact.emailaddress` and compare to `compare.emailaddress`

using a group of If commands? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Comment: If they are identical, they would fail the "does not equal"...because they are equal, not unequal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always start out somewhere, and then look for the perfect way. A slim example to help contributors get started on something that works for you could be:

```
$csv = import-csv C:\Temp\test.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

This will give you an object like this

```
firstname lastname email         
--------- -------- -----         
john      doe      john@doe.com  
johnny    doe      johnny@doe.com
jim       doe      jim@doe.com
```

This object can now be parsed in several ways. Depending on the string variable you would like to compare, i suggest you use ForEach-Object(or it's %{} abbreviation)

Like so:

```
$csv | % {
if ($_.Firstname -eq $Contact.Firstname) {Write-host "Match!" -fo green}
else{Write-host "No match :(" -fo red}

}
```

You will be able to loop through all the objects of the csv file, one by one, and compare their note properties.

Hope it helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

That was my thinking as well, I just want to check if any part of the contact has changed and if so update the whole record.

I'll just check each individual part and then if it see a change jump to the update the contact part.